# Python 3 argparse: Conditional argument only required if optional argument not provided?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

[Python 3/argparse]

Suppose my app expects a positional argument:

`myApp.py [desired_function]`

However, if the user provides a certain optional, then `desired_function` should NOT be required.

`myApp.py --list-functions`

In this instance, if `--list-functions` is passed, I want the application to proceed, leaving the variable I set `desired_function` into to remain empty, because my code will see that the user passed `--list-functions` and act accordingly.

However, if the user does **not** provide the `--list-functions` option, then the argument parser should produce an error because the user did not provide a required positional argument.

How can I have argparse make the `desired_function` positional required **only** if the user has not provided the optional?

Code I have so far:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="test app")
parser.add_argument("desired_function", help="The function desired", action="store", default="", dest="func")
parser.add_argument("--list-functions",help="List the available functions", action="store_true", default=False, dest="list_mode")
```

In this state, the invocation `myApp.py --list-functions` will fail with:

```
usage: myApp.py [-h] [--list-functions] desired_function
myApp.py: error: the following arguments are required: desired_function
```

Comment: Might it make sense to make `--list-functions` simply produce the `help` output, so `--list-functions` uses `action='help'` and is equivalent to `-h`, then incorporate the function listing into the `help` output? Alternatively, provide `choices` for `desired_function`, and let `argparse` do the work of displaying them?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple parser that makes the positional argument optional (nargs=?).

```
In [171]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [172]: parser.add_argument('func', nargs='?',default='foo')
In [173]: parser.add_argument('--list',action='store_true')
In [174]: args=parser.parse_args(['--list'])
In [175]: args
Out[175]: Namespace(func='foo', list=True)
In [176]: args=parser.parse_args(['bar'])
In [177]: args
Out[177]: Namespace(func='bar', list=False)
In [178]: parser.parse_args(['--list','bar'])
Out[178]: Namespace(func='bar', list=True)
In [179]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[179]: Namespace(func='foo', list=False)
```

Don't give a positional argument a `dest` parameter; it already gets one in the first string.  `store_true` action doesn't need a default; it gets `False` automatically.

With this set up, you could check `args.list`; it `True`, then just ignore the `args.func` value.  If `False`, use the `args.func`.  If you have given `func` a meaningful default, if shouldn't matter whether the user gives you a value or not.  In other words, it really isn't required. (And if required there's no point in defining a default).  Or you could object if they give you both:

```
In [184]: args=parser.parse_args(['--list','bar'])
In [185]: if args.list and args.func!='foo':
       parser.error('you stupid user ...')
   .....:     
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--list] [func]
ipython3: error: you stupid user ...
```

We could go the further step of placing these 2 arguments in a `mutually_exclusive_group`, and making that group `required`.  Such a group accepts one optional positional like this.  I think the docs are clear enough, but I could expand my answer if needed.

Comment: Does this still only allow for a single positional argument? i.e. if I for some reason wanted to add another argument after it, would `nargs="?"` interfere? Hypothetical example: `myApp.py processSomethingFromFile theFileToProcess.dat` where I'd have the filename be a second positional parameter. Also, even if I didn't do something like that, passing more than one positional argument should still be an error...?

Comment: Experiment with different combinations.  This is easier to see by doing than wordy explanations.

Comment: You can have multiple positionals.  But making more than one 'optional' (?+*) can be tricky if there is more than one way of allocating arguments.  mutually-exclusive grouping only allows one positional.