# Python argparse: how to include a '-v/--version' argument when a positional argument is required?

Tags: python, version, argparse

Basically I would like to have a `-v/--version` argument that behaves the same was as `-h/--help`:

It would be accepted even if a positional argument is required (obviously, you don't want to be forced to type a positional argument if the only thing you want is see the program version).

Right now, if a positional argument is required the single argument `-h`works fine by displaying the help message, but the single argument `-v` triggers an error message.
How to make -v behave like `-h` ?

In other words, how to make `-v` override the required positional argument ?

I tried to include `-v` as a choice within the positional argument but it's rejected as invalid (I suppose because of the -).

I also tried by using the `add_mutually_exclusive_group()` method but it's also not working (`-v` is rejected as an invalid choice, although it is part of the mutually exclusive group).

It looks like such a simple thing, as most programs have a `-v` option, even if they have required arguments. I wonder how they do it. It's frustrating...

Comment: [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53434478/python-argparse-ignore-other-options-when-a-specific-option-is-used), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60979532/argparse-ignore-positional-arguments-if-a-flag-is-set), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045926/python-3-argparse-conditional-argument-only-required-if-optional-argument-not-p). Use search.

Comment: From the docs, there's a `"version" action: `parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 2.0')` that exits like `help` after displaying its message.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I used the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53434478/python-argparse-ignore-other-options-when-a-specific-option-is-used). 
The reply by [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) is also useful, however it can not display longer information in multiple lines of text (it automatically removes all the line breaks and displays everything in a single line).